# execute_query with array as bind parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How do I use an Array (of Strings, or Integers) as bind parameter in `select_all` or `exec_query` for `in` where clauses?

```rb
# imagine a long a complicated SQL statement
# containing many CTEs and  
sql = <<~SQL
with things as (
  select ....
  where 
    x in ($1)
), morethings as (
  select
)

select 
sum(...), 
avg(...)
from morethings 
where categories in ($2)
SQL

binds = ??
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(
  sql,
  "query name",
   binds
).to_a
```

I can generate binds for scalars like this:

```rb
  ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute.new("name", "Pascal", ActiveRecord::Type::String.new)
```

but don't know how to supply array values and it seems I am missing something.

Background: I want to run some raw SQL queries in a Rails project with the parameters being properly escaped.
DB is Postgresql but I assume there is a DB agnostic way?
Or do I have to use the raw connection.

The query is not related to a model and translating to Arel is possible but does not really fit the workflow.

Comment: have you thought of looking at the splat operator https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rubys-splat-and-double-splat-operators-ceb753329a78/ ? or using named binds (allowing you to use a named Hash)?

Comment: @jad

i don't see how splats or named binds would solve the problem. The problem is passing an as parameter.

Comment: as the answer on this post suggests, it is probably worthwhile for you to use Arel to fix your problem.  if you really want to do this the way you are saying, and want to pass a list of arguments (rather than a named set of arguments as I also suggested) to the exec_query, you should pass them using a splat so that the exec query can deal with them ... but if you're writing pure SQL code and sending it using Ruby, then you're using Ruby wrongly

Comment: The number of elements in the array are unknown beforehand. Positional arguments are numbered. Nothing to do with splatting IMHO.

And no clue why I would use Ruby wrongly if I want to execute a SQL query.

Comment: Ruby on Rails has the whole object thing going for it.  if you're using Ruby you're much better off defining models, and using the relationships between the models to get to where you want to be.  it improves the debugging ability, and makes it much easier to code and understand once you get your head around it.  running pure SQL then hoping to work with the outcome is not portable, and a nightmare to debug, especially when working with other programmers

Comment: in terms of numbered parameters, just use `?` (instead of numbers) and splat the parameter list

Comment: The "whole object thing" and "relations" is actually the part that I want to skip. I want to run a raw SQL query for a report that does not relate to a model.

exec_query and select_all both take an array of binds, so i really don't understand how splatting would help, could you provide an example?

As for SQL vs. AR, I have a completely different oppinion on this. For my use case. Perhaps select_all/exec_query are the wrong way to go (thats what i try to find out) but for my use case SQL is much simpler, faster, uses less memory and easier to implement than going through AR.

Comment: I understand your use case, but would never consider this approach for any application that needs to be used or maintained.  tbh, if you're doing it this way, you should probably use another language, so that you don't have any ruby overhead at all.  the power of ROR lies in it's objects. you could be much better off using perl or python if you wanted to avoid the memory footprint. if you're using this code regularly, you would find that the use of models and memory would speed up the application due to caching of results by the underlying system, rather than raw SQL which isn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234286/discussion-between-pascal-and-jad).

Answer (score 0):

```
query = Arel::Table.new(:users).then do |u|
  users.project(users[Arel.star])
       .where(users[:id].in([1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']))
end

query.to_sql
# => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" IN (1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c')"
```

Comment: But honestly if you have a model why not just use it to generate the query?

Comment: hello @max

thanks for your Answers. I was hoping to get by without Arel :-)
I don't have a model for this particular query and i'll update the question to mbetter show this. 
It's a somewhat complicated query involving CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this safely if you're willing to do a little bit of string manipulation pre-processing. We build a string that can be cast to a typed postgres array once it arrives at the db.

```rb
user_ids = [1,3,5,34]
user_id_pg_array = '{' + user_ids.join(',') + '}' # evaluates to '{1,3,5,34}'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(
  "SELECT status FROM notifications WHERE user_id = ANY($1::int[]),
  "my fav query",
  [ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute.new("user_id_pg_arr", user_id_pg_arr, ActiveRecord::Type::String.new)]
)
```

I'm no Ruby or Rails expert, so there may be a better way. I expected the db client library to handle this for me without thinking about it, so maybe there's a way to do that if you drop down to a postgres-specific gem.